# Unable to bind parameters in Laravel raw query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to bind vars to my raw query,

```
$query = "SELECT 1 AS rank, 'CATEGORY' AS type, category_id AS id, name AS name
          FROM category_translations
          JOIN categories ON categories.id = category_translations.category_id
          WHERE name LIKE '%?%'";

$results = DB::select($query, ['ger']);
```

But I am unable to do so. I have tried by binding named params, and also using `DB::raw` inside `DB::select` without any success.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to used like that

```
$query = "SELECT 1 AS rank, 'CATEGORY' AS type, category_id AS id, name AS name
          FROM category_translations
          JOIN categories ON categories.id = category_translations.category_id
          WHERE name LIKE '% :nameSearch %'";

$results = DB::select(DB::raw($query), ['nameSearch' => 'ger']);
```

second way used like that

```
$searchText = "ger";
$results = DB::select(DB::raw($query), ['nameSearch' => "%".$searchText."%"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `%`'s to the bind value and not in the query (unless you `concat()` the values)...

```
$query = "SELECT 1 AS rank, 'CATEGORY' AS type, category_id AS id, name AS name
          FROM category_translations
          JOIN categories ON categories.id = category_translations.category_id
          WHERE name LIKE ?";

$results = DB::select($query, ['%ger%']);
```